# Optional queryParam in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

In my Gatling test I want to use queryParams but some have to be optional. Empty values gives errors so that is not an option. 
Is there a way to make a queryParam optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have some variable in the session (let's say `foo`) and based on the value of that variable, you determine whether or not a query parameter is required.

You can achieve this using `queryParamMap()` and providing an arbitrary `Expression[Map[String, Any]]` i.e. a `Session => Validation[Map[String, Any]]` function.

```
http("Getting issues")
  .get("https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues")
  .queryParamMap(session =>
    session("foo").validate[String].map {
      case "a" => Map("milestone" -> "1", "state" -> "open")
      case "b" => Map("milestone" -> "1", "state" -> "open", "author" -> "jenkins")
    })
```

Seek more information in official [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#query-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

My answer based on answer by Camilo Silva. Perhaps my solution  will be useful to community:

```
.queryParamMap(session =>
      session("experiment").validate[String].map {
        case value if value.nonEmpty => Map("experiment" -> value)
        case "" => Map()
      })
```